# Can't create eth accounts on wifi by using ganache-cli@v7.0.0-beta.0

Tags: testing, ganache, ganache-cli

I was previously getting `out of gas` error which was resolved by following [this](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/447) issue. Now i installed `ganache-cli@v7.0.0-beta.0` . It creates ethereum accounts on localhost if i write the following command;

> ganache-cli

The accounts on local host are as follows. If i use these accounts i didn't get out of gas error.

```
Ganache CLI v7.0.0-beta.0 (ganache-core: 3.0.0-beta.0)

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0x83086809b44625886bf2481c5892c1e882f5920c
(1) 0x1870a73b1cb795abb22e19eadfdaf38caef95bf7
(2) 0x2e0cd765b452834b521c93ab50196b024e86d468
(3) 0x9cd2ed6a814c673b523ac66de105f23a9d878538
(4) 0x9450eb5ee9edf0f9d9c5d1703a6c0f9740562762
(5) 0x6ed0d10d0dbc6f56d7df0c94858f80cb358d405e
(6) 0x9126102c8a67f5d6a89701c5ea1bfa764dc4e986
(7) 0xaf7e7565e8c48e12533e68915385f451e1edbaa0
(8) 0x6de462fd093b02d98f07804288e0e877a26655c0
(9) 0x95f999fd73311ed14bfb2318e336d6148d449ceb

Private Keys
==================
(0) 5c4539b82cf105ec2a0f14624ac89f8afef1b57e502ce3536a73b2c195080bb0
(1) b72a92b9bdd61ae616af8c259c53cc8b561371efde43675976edd893298eb5fb
(2) 61ce20461dd2dd6f9c60c075573e66a05228289c73a04fd50579a8567b75ea09
(3) c289c54194c0b7b5fb7352652518c404edfe121fa4be6de09221048f05ba990e
(4) dd53b427292a10ca8d1ab764d64de9d30a3d1f7f1efdb717a287a4100e658f67
(5) f5967273d55c9af91541d3abe8cf5c0ce88b2f5bdfba49e3f86deff9bf85ef85
(6) 8649abe4a2c96e48e766807dd3e5d355151dfbd0b6fdc8cd3d1dcf19ba73dd64
(7) 0a9c79a4e6dc247242ccc8104d47357ad197b5ab1764277964c95625a49a9e4b
(8) 9a8ab7807ca7a34e0eb58f546790ce5b1db8351c5972957eebb542ced3ff7b54
(9) 5acd77d7bd6ddf15db71cdcc7749cfafab1eb179065f5ef5d7416e577cf080cb

HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      install bargain breeze address giggle hurdle save grab network usual obscure wide
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Listening on localhost:8545
```

But now the **problem** is that i can not find any command for `ganache-cli`  to create these accounts on the wifi like we create the accounts using ganache application as follows;

[image]

Is there any way to link the `ganache-cli@v7.0.0-beta.0` to the actual ganache application or is there any command on `ganache-cli` to create accounts on wifi instead of local host.

**My Enviroment:**

- ganache-cli@v7.0.0-beta.0
- npm v6.9.0
- Node v10.16.1
- ganache application version 2.1.1
- Remix appVersion=0.7.7

Comment: Have you tried `--host=172.0.2.195 --port=whatever your port is`?

Comment: I used `ganache-cli --hostname:HTTP://172.0.2.195` but it says `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8545` . But i can create the eth account on the same host while i use ganache!

Comment: You have another process listening on 8545. Maybe it's that same ganache which you've used earlier in order to connect to your localhost with.

Comment: yes i closed it and it worked now

Comment: Glad to hear that :)